# What's the best android mobile phone for application development

Tags: android, hardware

I will have to develop some android applications. Witch mobile phone is better for application development : 
Google Nexus One / Htc Droid Incredible /  Htc Evo 4G / Motorola Droid ?

I have to develop on Android 2.1 and 2.2. All those devices will have the update I think.

Thanks for ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Nexus One - For right now it is setting the standard for android. Google controls the update cycle allowing you as a developer to get the lastest OS software as fast as possible for test your apps on the device. The whole idea behind the nexus one is to give a true android experience, so based on that I say the nexus is the way to go. That is not to say you shouldn't test on every phone you can get your hands on.